# Call remote cmdlet (ffmpeg) via Invoke-Command: "... not recognized as the name..."

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, invoke-command

I'm trying to call ffmpeg on a remote transcoding server via Powershell:

```
$session = new-pssession -computername transcodingserver
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock { powershell ffmpeg }
```

ffmpeg is correctly installed on the remote server and can be run there, but the remote call results in an error:

```
ffmpeg : The term 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ffmpeg : The te...rable program. :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : transcodingserver

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ffmpeg
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ffmpeg:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException
```

It seems to me like if the machine, I run `Invoke-Command` on, tries to run ffmpeg, which is not installed there. What do you have to do, to run ffmpeg on a remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `powershell` inside `-scriptblock {..}` because `Invoke-Command` itself is a powershell session(albeit a temporary one). Find the full path to `ffmpeg` executable and run the following

```powershell
$session = new-pssession -computername transcodingserver
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock { & "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"}
```

or you can execute the command directly, without `new-pssession`

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName transcodingserver -scriptblock { 
    & "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue solved it with

```
$media = Invoke-Command -ComputerName backupsvr -ScriptBlock { import-module "\program files\symantec\backup exec\modules\bemcli\bemcli"; Get-BEMedia}
```

Comment: i was wondering why my `Install-Junction` wasnt working. you nailed it. the `Import-Module Carbon` was necessary.